# Loading date from database to a form using javascript in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have a form where **Date** needs to loaded from saved values in database for a particular event.
Laravel is submitting correct date to the form. It returns `[{"Date":"2016-09-15"}]`

Here is my code:

```js
$('#ActDate').empty();
$.each(data, function (index, day){
  $('#ActDate').append('<input value="' + day.Date '"/>');
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label align="right" for="Date" class="control-label col-xs-2">Date : </label>
  <input type="date" class="col-xs-3" id="ActDate"  name="ActDate" value="">
</div>
```

In console this error message is shown

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Its near `$('#ActDate').append('<input value="'+day.Date'"/>');` this line.

I have beginner level knowledge about JavaScript.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: You're missing a plus sign: `'+day.Date+'` when concatenating your string in your javascript... and what bharat said. :)

Comment: Thank, I fixed it.error message is gone. but still values are not loading for date filed.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add input field in new input field. you have to write like below code

```
$('#ActDate').val(day.Date);
```

Comment: ...plus the fact that he's doing it in a loop, which will just overwrite the last value in each iteration. Guess that's why he used `append`.

Comment: put alert and check your date is coming like `alert(day.Date)`

Comment: No, it is not returning anything..
here, this is how I get values for accessing databases.three variables are taken.
`$.getJSON('/xxxxxxx/day?yearID=&itemID=&actID=' +yearID + itemID + actID, function(data){//functions are here }`

Comment: Problem is with your response, check your response

Comment: what do you mean? how to fix it?

Comment: I means to say check what is `day` in your code and from where its coming and what is wrong with it, problem is there must be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124383/discussion-between-sachith-and-bharat-patidar).

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error:
`"'+day.Date'"` is missing the second '+' sign
should be: `"'+day.Date+'"`

Comment: Its not possible to add input field in another input field

Comment: That too, your suggestion is also valid